# Need Message in JSP Page to Change using Boolean

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement, servlets, boolean

I am a **student** working on a project where the Servlet checks the employee directory for an id or last name based on the user-entered info in the JSP page. I need the boolean "employeeFound" to output a message ("project4SearchMessage") on whether or not an employee has been found. So far, it only shows one message for whether the employee was found or not. Need some help, thank you!

```
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    //Get the EmployeeDirectory instance from the ServletContext
    EmployeeDirectory employeeSearch = 
        (EmployeeDirectory)context.getAttribute("employeeDirectory");

    //Get the search type and search term from the HTML form
    String searchTerm = request.getParameter("searchTerm");
    String searchType = request.getParameter("searchType");

    //Search for employees by calling method in the EmployeeDirectory
    //instance and pass the search type and the search term
    //to the method
    if (searchType.equals("id")) {
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setSearchTerm(searchTerm);
        search.setSearchType(searchType);
        employeeSearch.searchByEmployeeID(search);
        //place the Search object into the session   
        session.setAttribute("search", search);
        if (search.isEmployeeFound() == false) {
            String project4SearchMessage = "No Employee found.";
            session.setAttribute("project4SearchMessage", project4SearchMessage);
        }

        if (search.isEmployeeFound() == true) {
            String project4SearchMessage = "Employee Found";
            session.setAttribute("project4SearchMessage", project4SearchMessage);
        }
    }

    if (searchType.equals("lastName")) {
        Search search = new Search();
        search.setSearchTerm(searchTerm);
        search.setSearchType(searchType);
        employeeSearch.searchByEmployeeLastName(search);
        //place the Search object into the session
        session.setAttribute("search", search);
        if (search.isEmployeeFound() == false) {
            String project4SearchMessage = "No Employee found.";
            session.setAttribute("project4SearchMessage", project4SearchMessage);
        }

        if (search.isEmployeeFound() == true) {
            String project4SearchMessage = "Employee Found";
            session.setAttribute("project4SearchMessage", project4SearchMessage);
        }
    }

    //Employee Search Results page url
    String url = "/jsp/searchResults.jsp";

    //instantiate a RequestDispatcher object and assign the url
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);

    //forward to jsp page
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Here is the JSP:

```
<h3>${project4SearchMessage}</h3>
<h2>Employee Search Results:</h2>
  <table>        
    <tr>
    <td> Search Type </td>
    <td> ${search.searchType} </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
    <td> Search Term </td>
    <td> ${search.searchTerm} </td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="employee" items="${search.employeeList}">
      <tr>
      <td> Employee </td>
      <td> ${employee.toString()}</td>
      </tr> 
    </c:forEach>
  </table>
```

Here is the boolean:

```
private String searchType;
private String searchTerm;
private List employeeList = new ArrayList();
private boolean employeeFound;

/**
 * Empty constructor for the Search object
 */
public Search() {

}

/**
 * Returns the value of searchType.
 */
public String getSearchType() {
    return searchType;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of searchType.
 * @param searchType The value to assign searchType.
 */
public void setSearchType(String searchType) {
    this.searchType = searchType;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of searchTerm.
 */
public String getSearchTerm() {
    return searchTerm;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of searchTerm.
 * @param searchTerm The value to assign searchTerm.
 */
public void setSearchTerm(String searchTerm) {
    this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of employeeList.
 */
public List getEmployeeList() {
    return employeeList;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of employeeList.
 * @param employeeList The value to assign employeeList.
 */
public void setEmployeeList(List employeeList) {
    this.employeeList = employeeList;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of foundEmployee.
 */
public boolean isEmployeeFound() {
    return employeeFound;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of foundEmployee.
 * @param foundEmployee The value to assign foundEmployee.
 */
public void setEmployeeFound(boolean employeeFound) {
    this.employeeFound = employeeFound;
}

/**
 * The addFoundEmployee method adds the employee object to the List of found
 * Employee objects.
 */
public void addFoundEmployee(Employee employee) {
    employeeList.add(employee);
}
```

Here are the EmployeeDirectory methods:

```
/**
 * The searchByEmployeeID method searches for an Employee in the database by 
 * employee id.
 *
 *@param search search object from the SearchResultsServlet class
 */
public void searchByEmployeeID(Search search) {

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        String queryString = "SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, ssn, dept, room, phone "
                + " FROM employees " 
                + "WHERE emp_id = " + search.getSearchTerm() + ";";

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

        if (resultSet != null) {
            //if the query returns any rows set boolean to true
            search.setEmployeeFound(true);

            //finds and returns the next complete entry
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                //instantiate a new Employee object
                Employee employee = new Employee();

                //set instance variables from the row from the database
                employee.setId(resultSet.getString("emp_id"));
                employee.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                employee.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
                employee.setSsn(resultSet.getString("ssn"));
                employee.setDept(resultSet.getString("dept"));
                employee.setRoom(resultSet.getString("room"));
                employee.setPhone(resultSet.getString("phone"));

                //each new Employee object added to the Search object
                search.addFoundEmployee(employee);

            }

        } else {
            //if the query does not return any rows set boolean to false
            search.setEmployeeFound(false);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        System.err.println("Error in connection.ecting to database "
                + sqlException);
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.err.println("General Error");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    //close the connection
    } finally {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            System.err.println("Error in connection.ecting to database "
                    + sqlException);
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.err.println("General Error");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }            
}


/**
 * The searchByEmployeeLastName method searches for an Employee in the  
 * database by employee last name.
 *
 *@param search search object from the SearchResultsServlet class
 */
public void searchByEmployeeLastName(Search search) {

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        String queryString = "SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, ssn, dept, room, phone "
                + " FROM employees " 
                + "WHERE last_name LIKE '" + search.getSearchTerm() + "%'";

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

        if (resultSet != null) {
            //if the query returns any rows set boolean to true
            search.setEmployeeFound(true);

            //finds and returns the next complete entry
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                //instantiate a new Employee object
                Employee employee = new Employee();

                //set instance variables from the row from the database
                employee.setId(resultSet.getString("emp_id"));
                employee.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                employee.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
                employee.setSsn(resultSet.getString("ssn"));
                employee.setDept(resultSet.getString("dept"));
                employee.setRoom(resultSet.getString("room"));
                employee.setPhone(resultSet.getString("phone"));

                //each new Employee object added to the Search object
                search.addFoundEmployee(employee);

            }

        } else {
            //if the query does not return any rows set boolean to false
            search.setEmployeeFound(false);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        System.err.println("Error in connection.ecting to database "
                + sqlException);
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.err.println("General Error");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    //close the connection
    } finally {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            System.err.println("Error in connection.ecting to database "
                    + sqlException);
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.err.println("General Error");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote this question, at least explain why so I can change it.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but it is not clear where you are having the issue.  Can you clarify what you want to do and what the code does? also, adding the *relevant* code that displays (or not) what you want on the JSP is necessary (without it, how can we tell if your JSP is coded correctly or not?) - Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question

Comment: I want to check whether an employee is found, and return a message indicating whether the employee is found or not. So far, the if statements I am using with the boolean isEmployeeFound() are only returning the same message for whether an employee is found or not. I need help with the if statements or the boolean in returning the correct message.

Comment: and does your `searchByEmployeeID(...)` or `searchByLastName(...)` set the `isEmployeeFound` flag correctly?

Comment: I can add that code as well. I think it does, but might be wrong.

Comment: I also tried this instead of using ${project4SearchMessage} but didn't work: <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${search.isEmployeeFound() == false}" >
          <tr>
          <td><h3>Employee not found</h3></td>
          </tr>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
        <c:forEach var="employee" items="${search.employeeList}">
          <tr>
          <td> Employee </td>
          <td> ${employee.toString()}</td>
          </tr> 
        </c:forEach>
      </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>

Comment: I think you are doing this `search.setEmployeeFound(true);` when the results is not null (i.e. inside the `if` statement) but what if the results is not null and the result set is empty? My guess is that you would see the flag being set to true but with no employees in the list (which would be incorrect) -  can you verify this is not the case?

Comment: In fact, the `ResultSet` object is never null so your flag is always going to return `true` - See the javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are setting the flag at the beginning of going thru the result set.

However, Result sets are never null (See [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)))

```
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

        /**********************************/
        /** your result set is never null */
        /** this is incorrect             */
        /**********************************/
        if (resultSet != null) {
            //if the query returns any rows set boolean to true
            search.setEmployeeFound(true);
            //...
        }
```

**Instead** you need to set the flag at the end of processing the result set.
if a result set was added to the list, set the flag to true.

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    //instantiate a new Employee object
    Employee employee = new Employee();

    //set instance variables from the row from the database
    employee.setId(resultSet.getString("emp_id"));
    // ... etc.

    //each new Employee object added to the Search object
    search.addFoundEmployee(employee);    
}

// employeeList is never null so we don't check for it, just its size
if( search.getEmployeeList().size() > 0 ){
     search.setEmployeeFound(true);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!